# In python matplotlib, can the legend be turned on inside the pyplot.plt command?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am using the inline list construct lately and plotting multiple lines in a single command for debugging.

Lets assume the following code that creates a list or numpy.array of curves, plots them while assigning a label to each line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t=np.linspace(0,np.pi*2,50)
data=[np.sin(n*t) for n in range(3)]
[plt.plot(t,d,label=f'T={n}') for n,d in enumerate(data)]
```

Of course, the legend will not show unless we run

```
plt.legend()
```

How can we include this command in the plot statement eliminating the need for an additional line of code?

Something like

```
[plt.plot(t,d,label=f'T={n}',legend=True) for n,d in enumerate(data)]
```

or even

```
[plt.plot(t,d,label=f'T={n}',legend={loc:'best', <insert other legend kwargs here>}) for n,d in enumerate(data)]
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to plot all the lines in a list?

Comment: I guess I should rephrase my question: Why is doing it in one line more readable than doing it in three? To the best of my knowledge, `plt.plot()` doesn't offer a legend parameter or keyword-argument.

Comment: I think the best you could do in one line is `[plt.plot(t,d,label=f'T={n}') for n,d in enumerate(data)]; plt.legend()`

Comment: Its not readability that much but versatility or ease of use. I am debuging and plotting multiple curves of similar quantities in a script in an IDE (spyder) and instead of either selecting multiple lines and hitting "run" or hitting "run" multiple times for each line, I would prefer hitting "run" once just being on the line (without selecting). It also helps keeping things tidy when plotting curves in a figure intensive code, which I am writing

Comment: I guess I can also create an auxiliary function that passes all the appropriate arguments to the approprtiate pyplot methods (.plot, .figure, .legend etc) - a kind of overloading. In that case it is a different question that I need to search if it's been answered or create a new question.